# Function not defined in Javascript using Paper JS

Tags: javascript, paperjs

**UPDATE**
making the colorChange function global solves the problem

I am trying to change the color of the path when the button 'Red' is clicked using colorChange function .Regardless of my logic , the error says 'Function 'colorChange' is not defined' . The internal paper js functions like path() are working , but my function isn't .

```
<head>
<!-- Load the Paper.js library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paper.js"></script>
<!-- Load external PaperScript and associate it with myCanvas -->
<script type="text/paperscript" src="js/myScript.js" canvas="myCanvas"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick='colorChange(id)' id='red'>Red</button> // Using it here
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize="true"></canvas>
</body>
```

Here's myScript.js for canvas ID='myCanvas' :

```
var myPath={};

var colorChange=function(id){  //function I defined doesn't work
    myPath=new Path();
    myPath.strokeColor=id;
}

function onMouseDown(event){   //this works
    myPath=new Path();
    myPath.add(event.point);
}
```

Comment: @Hacketo the question isn't a duplicate . yes i did try your proposed solution. But it doesn't work .

Comment: i tried calling the function from the console , i failed again

Comment: It has nothing to do with the way the function is declared (as in the duplicate question). This question should be reopened.

Comment: the problem is that `colorChange` exists only in the scope of that paperscript and is not visible outside. In your case, it should be defined globally to be used as handler to button clicks.

Comment: @manji thank you ! I was disappointed by the response of stack overflow moderators. This made my day !

Answer (score 0):

Move the `script` tag to the bottom of the page, not in the header. That should make it work.